# Oracle stoplist on multilanguage column index

Tags: oracle, text, full-text-search

I don't understand how does oracle stoplist work on multilanguage column indexing.
I know how to create a multi_column lexer but I don't see an option to associate a specific stoplist to each specific language lexer.
Moreover I'm reading that

> Blockquote
>   At index time, the lexer preference AUTO_LEXER automatically detects the language of the document and tokenizes and stems the document appropriately.
>   Blockquote

MULTI_LEXER is not mentioned. Is it right to suppose that on a multi lexer the correct stoplist is applied on each row depending on row language?